# Can't convert SubjectAreaGroup List to SubjectAreaGroup List???

Tags: c#

Having a problem retrieving  a list of items from the database. This is what I am attempting.

```
List<SubjectAreaGroup> subjectAreas = examInstance.CurrentQuestionGroup.QuestionTypeGroups.Select(q => q.SubjectAreaGroups).toList();
```

But when I do this, it gives me an error that I can't convert a SubjectAreaGroup List to a... SubjectAreaGroup List. If they are the same thing then why can't I convert them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the issue is due to the `q.SubjectAreaGroups` property giving a `List<SubjectAreaGroup>` for *each* QuestionTypeGroup. Thus, your `Select` statement is giving you a two-level sequence: `IEnumerable<List<SubjectAreaGroup>>`.

To resolve this, you simply need to flatten your resulting sequences into one sequence using the [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) operator:

```
List<SubjectAreaGroup> subjectAreas = 
    examInstance.CurrentQuestionGroup
                .QuestionTypeGroups
                .SelectMany(q => q.SubjectAreaGroups)
                .ToList();
```